# Chrome console prints out function source code instead of doing something

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, sublimetext2

I'm trying to make a simple blackjack game on Javascript. I really don't understand why the function does not work properly?

```
var OurHand = 0;
var TheirHand = 0;

function dealCards() {
    OurHand += Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1
    OurHand += Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1
    TheirHand += Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1
    TheirHand += Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1
}
```

Comment: did you remember the parenthesis? use `dealCards()` not `dealCards`

Comment: Call it: `dealCards` without parenthesis

Comment: yes I call it "dealCards" in the console, and the variables do not change at all.

Comment: you need to call it with the parenthesis `()`. See the example below.

Comment: I kinda get it now, thanks for blazin' fast help!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to execute your code using `functionName()` with parenthesis. Here is your example working & writing "done" in the console as an result.

```
var OurHand = 0;
var TheirHand = 0;

function dealCards() {
    OurHand += Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1
    OurHand += Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1
    TheirHand += Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1
    TheirHand += Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1
    console.log('Done dealing cards.')
}

dealCards() // this will execute your code of the dealCards function

console.log(OurHand)
console.log(TheirHand)
```

Comment: But don't I execute it in the console by typing "dealCards" ?

Comment: nope :) you can read more about that here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_invocation.asp or here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call